# Re-Showing the Hairline

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a two `TableViewControllers` with Embedded Navigation Controllers. `ViewController-1` shows the hairline/shadow under the nav bar and `ViewController-2` doesn't show it when I navigate to it. Navigation is done using the Push Segue

To hide the navigation bar in `ViewController-2` I adding the following lines in `ViewWillAppear` the following:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

When I use the back button to go back to ViewController-1 the Hairline disappears there too but I do not want it to. Is there anyway to ensure that the hairline doesn't hide in `ViewController-1`?

I have tried :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

but without much success.

Comment: You are the one who destroyed the shadow, and now you are complaining that you destroyed the shadow??? — To show the shadow, do the opposite of what you already did: give the navigation bar a (nonempty) background image and a (nonempty) shadow image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `viewWillDisappear` (or maybe the `viewDidDisappear`) method of `ViewController-2`, add code to undo the changes made in `viewWillAppear`.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Comment: Should have thought of that. Super simple. Thanks